# Opencart Ajax Error unexpected token <

Tags: ajax, opencart

I'm using OpenCart 1.5.1.3 and having this strange error on Guest Shipping in Ajax. I'm getting the error "Unexpected token <". 
I have tried everyting, change the Ajax code, look at the controller, but no luck. You can try it yourself at http://www.biancabonte.nl/shop/. Put something in the cart and checkout Direct instead of registering. Then the problem occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly due to an error message being output by your store, which precedes the AJAX JSON content. Check your error logs around the time you made/make the request. While they won't contain the `<` character since they're not formatted like the ones output by PHP, they will still have the actual message. Your error logs will either be in the `SYSTEM > ERROR LOGS` in the admin, or in your cpanel/plesk/other control panel under logs usually